# How to get a pointer to last inserted element of a std::vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, std, stdvector, push-back

I came up with the following snipped but it looks quite hacky.

```
vector<int> collection;
collection.push_back(42);
int *pointer = &(*(collection.end()--));
```

Is there an easy way to get a pointer to the last inserted element?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For `std::vector`, `back()` returns a reference to the last element, so `&collection.back()` is what you need.

In C++17, `emplace_back` returns a reference to the new element. You could use it instead of `push_back`:

```
vector<int> collection;
int *pointer = &collection.emplace_back(42);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Moreover, if the vector holds `std::pair`s, do you know how to get a pointer to the second element of the last pair?

Comment: `&(collection.back().second)`

Comment: @PeterWood Gives me a bad function exception if I bind that pointer to a function. Could it have to do with the pointer and thus with the question? Otherwise I would ask another one to not mix up topics.

Comment: @danijar If you're sure you have the parentheses in the right place, then the problem is likely something else. New question.